# Как вызвать запрос VK SDK в RxJava?

Tags: java, android, rxjava

```
    request.executeWithListener(new VKRequestListener() { 
@Override 
public void onComplete(VKResponse response) { 
//Do complete stuff 
} 
@Override 
public void onError(VKError error) { 
//Do error stuff 
} 
@Override 
public void attemptFailed(VKRequest request, int attemptNumber, int totalAttempts) { 
//I don't really believe in progress 
} 
});
```

Суть в том что у библиотек уже есть свой способ вызова запросов. Я хочу научиться использовать Rx. Как мне в RX добавить этот запрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте `Observable` и создавайте события, которые будут получены подписчиками как-то так:

```
Observable.create(subscriber -> {
    request.executeWithListener(new VKRequestListener() { 

        @Override 
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) { 
            //Do complete stuff 
            subscriber.onNext(response);
            subscriber.onComplete();
        } 
        @Override 
        public void onError(VKError error) { 
            subscriber.onError(error.getException());
        } 
        @Override 
        public void attemptFailed(VKRequest request, int attemptNumber, int totalAttempts) { 
            //I don't really believe in progress 
            subscriber.onError(new Exception());
        } 
    }); 
})
.subscribe(
     response -> System.out.println(response),
     e -> System.out.println(e.getMessage())
)
```

Comment: Я немного другое хотел. Я немного другое хотел. У меня есть класс `RestVK` в нем прописанны запросы для VK.
Я хотел использовать в MainActivity Observerble от RX чтобы использовать метод для запроса к примеру RestVK.groupsGet(). 
Который бы обрабатывал запрос и в потоке данных, вернул бы мне VkResponse, а уже после я бы в subscribe прописывал бы все что мне надо. ui и т.д.

Comment: @EraNewGames, не очень понял что у вас есть и что вы хотите, но, вроде, я именно это вам и написал) Возможно, вам стоит показать что у вас есть. Т.е. что именно и как надо сделать.

Comment: Согласен набор слов получился). Если коротко то я хочу отделить запросы VK. И вызывать запросы в Observable в любой части кода.

Comment: @EraNewGames, ну так я вам, вроде, это и написал... Что именно не устраивает?..

Comment: @EraNewGames, здесь дело в том, как либа ВКшная сделана. Ничто не мешает вам взять retrofit и самостоятельно реализовать вызовы всех методов. Кода будет как раз очень мало.